# Rails 4 Subdomain on production (Nginx + Passenger)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, passenger

I've setup 1 apps for ex, example.com with devise auth on it. So when user signup, it will automatically create the subdomain for that user, for ex: user1.example.com where it will showing user profile, (as i follow here: https://railsapps.github.io/tutorial-rails-subdomains.html)

In my development env which is i use pow, everything work fine but not for production env. I can't access my user subdomain. It said something like "because the DNS lookup failed".

So my question, do I miss something to configure from the nginx site? or maybe from the dns?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your dns and nginx config will have to allow for wildcard sub domains.

Comment: @japed can you share with me your setting for the dns n nginx config?

Comment: For [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#wildcard_names) essentially `server_name *.example.org` and same in dns settings for your domain - have the DNS entry as *.

Comment: @japed for dns, should i put it under CNAME or A Record?

Comment: You'll need it to be the A record.

Comment: It work nicely.. Thank you @japed.. can you please post it answer below instead of comment so i can mark your answer acceptable +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#wildcard_names) essentially `server_name *.example.org` and same in dns settings for your domain - have the DNS entry as * as an A record.